# Code transformation from BS4 to lxml parser

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, pycharm, lxml

I am working on a project to extract specific information from locally stored HTML files by using BS4. As I do have a considerably big amount of files (>1 Million) speed and performance is the key for having a useful code browsing through all files. Until now I am working with BS4 as I was working before on a web crawler and I thought BS4 is pretty easy and handy. However if it comes to big data, BS4 is way to slow. I read about the `lxml parser` and `html.parser` , that seems to be the most easy and fastest parsers among python for HTML documents.

So my code right now looks like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import glob
import os
import re
import contextlib


@contextlib.contextmanager
def stdout2file(fname):
    import sys
    f = open(fname, 'w')
    sys.stdout = f
    yield
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
    f.close()


def trade_spider():
    os.chdir(r"C:\Users\XXX")
    with stdout2file("output.txt"):
        for file in glob.iglob('**/*.html', recursive=True):
            with open(file, encoding="utf8") as f:
                contents = f.read()
                soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, "html.parser")
                for item in soup.findAll("ix:nonfraction"):
                    if re.match(".*SearchTag", item['name']):
                        print(file.split(os.path.sep)[-1], end="| ")
                        print(item['name'], end="| ")
                        print(item.get_text())
                        break
trade_spider()
```

It opens a text file, goes into my set directory (os.chdir(..)), seraches through all files ending .html, reads the content and if it finds tag  with name attribute "SearchTag" it takes the related HTML text and prints it to my open text file. After one match there is a break and it will continue with the next one. 
So what I read is, that BS4 does this all in memory, which increases porcessing time significantly.

That's why I wanted to alter my code with using either lxml (prefered) or html.parser.

Anyone of you being a genius and is able to alter my code to use lxml parser without changing the initial easy idea I had on this?

Any help appreciated on this as I am totally stucked....

UPDATE:

```
import lxml.etree as et
import os
import glob

import contextlib


@contextlib.contextmanager
def stdout2file(fname):
    import sys
    f = open(fname, 'w')
    sys.stdout = f
    yield
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
    f.close()


def skip_to(fle, line):
        with open(fle) as f:
            pos = 0
            cur_line = f.readline().strip()
            while not cur_line.startswith(line):
                pos = f.tell()
                cur_line = f.readline()
            f.seek(pos)
            return et.parse(f)


def trade_spider():
    os.chdir(r"F:\04_Independent Auditors Report")
    with stdout2file("auditfeesexpenses.txt"):
        for file in glob.iglob('**/*.html', recursive=True):
            xml = skip_to(file, "<?xml")
            tree = xml.getroot()
            nsmap = {"ix": tree.nsmap["ix"]}
            fractions = xml.xpath("//ix:nonFraction[contains(@name, 'AuditFeesExpenses')]", namespaces=nsmap)
            for fraction in fractions:
                print(file.split(os.path.sep)[-1], end="| ")
                print(fraction.get("name"), end="| ")
                print(fraction.text, end=" \n")
                break

trade_spider()
```

I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/6930p/PycharmProjects/untitled/Versuch/lxmlparser.py", line 43, in <module>
    trade_spider()
  File "C:/Users/6930p/PycharmProjects/untitled/Versuch/lxmlparser.py", line 33, in trade_spider
    xml = skip_to(file, "<?xml")
  File "C:/Users/6930p/PycharmProjects/untitled/Versuch/lxmlparser.py", line 26, in skip_to
    return et.parse(f)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3427, in lxml.etree.parse (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:79720)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1803, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:116182)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1823, in lxml.etree._parseFilelikeDocument (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:116474)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1718, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFilelike (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:115235)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1139, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFilelike (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:110109)
  File "parser.pxi", line 573, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:103323)
  File "parser.pxi", line 679, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:104936)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 324, in lxml.etree._ExceptionContext._raise_if_stored (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:10656)
  File "parser.pxi", line 362, in lxml.etree._FileReaderContext.copyToBuffer (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:100828)
  File "C:\Users\6930p\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 1789: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Using lxml itself will be the fastest approach, add a sample of your data

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Edited OP with a sample. However this is only a very short section, the original html files contain up to 3000 lines....

Comment: What do you want to parse? Also are there namespaces?

Comment: I want to parse the <ix:NonFraction Tag with nameattribute "...AuditFeesExpenses" and if it is found i would  need the Text >3,420< and >3,600<. Yes there are name attributes that define each tag unique. In my case, as mentioned before, "...AuditFeesExpenses" as value of the Nameattribute.

Comment: Can you add the start of the file which includes the namespace definition?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham:  Edited OP. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: If you post one full file in pastebin if possible that would make life easier to give you a complete working example

Comment: Can I somehow upload a whole file without copy + paste the content into my question (it seems like the body on stackflow is limited to 30.000 letters and I have 190.000 on my HTML file)?!

Comment: http://pastebin.com/

Comment: http://pastebin.com/rsyVhThY
Hope it works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bit of work to tidy up the html as per your html file in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/rsyVhThY), the following finds `nonFraction` tags with name attributes containing `'AuditFeesExpenses'`:

```
import lxml.etree as et

def skip_to(fle, line):
    with open(fle) as f:
        pos = 0
        cur_line = f.readline().strip()
        while not cur_line.startswith(line):
            pos = f.tell()
            cur_line = f.readline()
        f.seek(pos)
        return et.parse(f)

xml = skip_to("/home/padraic/Downloads/sample_html_file.html","<?xml")
tree = xml.getroot()
# one mapping is None ->  None: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'
nsmap = {k: v for k, v in tree.nsmap.items() if k}

print(xml.xpath("//ix:nonFraction[contains(@name, 'AuditFeesExpenses')]", namespaces=nsmap))
```

Output:

```
[<Element {http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL}nonFraction at 0x7f5b9e91c560>, <Element {http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL}nonFraction at 0x7f5b9e91c5a8>]
```

To pull the text and name:

```
fractions = xml.xpath("//ix:nonFraction[contains(@name, 'AuditFeesExpenses')]", namespaces=nsmap)

for fraction in fractions:
    print(fraction.get("name"))
    print(fraction.text)
```

Which will give you:

```
ns19:AuditFeesExpenses
1,850
ns19:AuditFeesExpenses
2,400
```

Also if you are just using the ix namespace you can just pull that

```
tree = xml.getroot()
nsmap = {"ix":tree.nsmap["ix"]}

fractions = xml.xpath("//ix:nonFraction[contains(@name, 'AuditFeesExpenses')]", namespaces=nsmap)

for fraction in fractions:
    print(fraction.get("name"))
    print(fraction.text)
```

So the full woking code:

```
def trade_spider():
    os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Independent Auditors Report")
    with stdout2file("auditfeesexpenses.txt"):
        for file in glob.iglob('**/*.html', recursive=True):
            xml = skip_to(file, "<?xml")
            tree = xml.getroot()
            nsmap = {"ix": tree.nsmap["ix"]}
            fractions = xml.xpath("//ix:nonFraction[contains(@name, 'AuditFeesExpenses')]", namespaces=nsmap)
            for fraction in fractions:
                print(file.split(os.path.sep)[-1], end="| ")
                print(fraction.get("name"), end="| ")
                print(fraction.text, end="|")
```

In place of *os.chdir* you can also:

```
for file in glob.iglob('C:/Users/Independent Auditors Report/**/*.html', recursive=True):
```

Comment: Perfect! Appreciate your help on this! I'll run this code for a few samples on my computer and give you feedback. Just one question, how do I get the os.chdir operator into this code as I need to paste a raw directory path into my code to brwose a whole directory and its subfolder?

Comment: Keep your own logic, just pass file to the skip_to function, there are some other options with lxml but see how you go using the logic above and we can go from there

Comment: Edit OP. If I used your version of the code that is parsing only one file with the 'xml = skip_to(...)' operator it works perfectly. But when I am trying to insert my logic of os.chdir I don't get the code working?

Comment: @FlorianSchramm, I rolled back your edit but I will add full working code in minute

Comment: Pretty sweet! It works perfectly! Thank you for helping me out on this so quickly!

Comment: I am currently having some issues with my code... It worked fine for the first time, but now I get a large error messag. I included my Code and error message in my OP. Would you mind having a look at it? It don't know what's going wrong? The code starts to give me desired output of the first three files but afterwards it cracks down?!

Comment: @FlorianSchramm, better to ask a new question, add a link when you do and I will have a look, the issue is not really related to lxml, it is an issue with encoding

Comment: Ok, I figured out that it is an issue with my os.chdir(r"F:\04_Independent Auditors Report\2012\October") line. It only works if I set my directory to the last subfolder. If I leave the '2012\October' it cracks down. 04_Independent Auditors Report consists of 5 subolders, each including up to 12 subfolders with HTML files. Could it be that for file in glob.iglob('**/*.html', recursive=True): is only working for my first subfolder and it's first subfolder (F:\04_Independent Auditors Report\2012\October). When finishing October it is not continuing with the next folder (November).

Comment: The problem is there is no mapping for  `0x8f` in cp1252, you would need to  set the encoding to utf-8

Comment: Works perfectly as mentioned in my other question. Appreciated (again) your help on this.

Comment: No prob, you're welcome, the issue is simply some files contain data that cannot be parsed using cp1252 as it does not have a mapping for those bytes, utf8 i generally the best route to go down when dealing with encoding.

Comment: Alright, I'll keep that in mind.  In my BS4 crawler I also used utf-8 encondig, don't know why I haven't done it this time...